# Simple Proof of FT of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

Which proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra requires minimum mathematical maturity and has the best chances to be understood by an amateur with knowledge of complex numbers and polynomials?

Comment: Maybe using Liouville's theorem that states that every bounded holomorphic function is constant. Let $f$ be the polynomial in cause. Assume it has no complex roots. Consider the function $\frac{1}{f}$ which is now holomorphic and bounded, therefore constant which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think Iulia's proof is the simplest. Some others: choose an appropriately large disk on which $|p(z)|$ attains its global minimum, then prove that this minimum is zero. Another is to assume there are no roots, then apply Cauchy's integral formula to $\frac{1}{zp(z)}$, integrated around a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin. This says that these integrals are constant, but a direct estimate says that they go to zero as $R \to \infty$, so you have a contradiction.

Comment: Note that most proofs of the FTA proceed by showing that there is *one* root. After that, it's easy: you factor, then the new thing has a root, so you factor that, then that has a root, etc.

Comment: Relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra Though some of these answers are not at your level.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the polynomial has no zeros.  Then every value of $f(z)$ has a direction.
Draw a large circle, where $z^n$ dominates over the other terms in the polynomial.  As you travel around the circle, the direction of $f(z)$ is near the direction of $z^n$, so it rotates $n$ times as $z$ goes once around the circle.
Now gradually shrink the circle, until it is nearly nothing.  $f(z)$ is nearly constant as you go around the circle, so it doesn't rotate at all as you go around the circle.
The number of rotations must change from $n$ to $0$ at some point.  But unless $f(z)=0$ somewhere, the number of rotations is continuous.  So $f(z)=0$ somewhere.

Comment: I don't think the rigorous version of this proof is nearly as easy to understand as the intuitive sketch.